# Invalid format with Json when converting DataTable with Json.Net

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, json, extjs, json.net

I'm trying to convert DataTable to JSON using Newtonsoft.JSON but found that the output is not what ExtJS grid and chart would expect.

My code is

```
string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt, Formatting.Indented,
                            new JsonSerializerSettings
                            {
                                ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
                            });
```

and this returns Json string as

```
"[{\"DAYDATE\":\"2012-05-22T00:15:00\",\"SERIES1\":3.65}]"
```

If I remove '\' and start and end double quotes it works fine with ExtJS.

I also tried changing date format to more JSON'y

```
string javascriptJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(entry, new JavaScriptDateTimeConverter());
```

results in

```
"[{\"DAYDATE\":new Date(1337642100000),\"SERIES1\":3.65}]"
```

still no luck

Comment: Forgot to add ExtJS grid throws error 200

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your JSON is getting double serialized.  Although you did not show your full controller code, I'm guessing that you are doing something like this:

```
    public ActionResult GetDataTable()
    {
        // (... code to build data table omitted for brevity ...)

        // Serialize data table using Json.Net to avoid circular reference error
        string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt,
            new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore,
                Formatting = Formatting.Indented
            });

        return Json(output);
    }
```

The `Json()` method also invokes serialization.  Normally, in an MVC controller, you would just use the `Json()` method to serialize your return object, and not use Json.Net separately.  I can see you are using Json.Net here to try to get around the exception that happens due to circular references when you try to serialize a data table.  If you are going to serialize manually, then you need to return the data in a way that it will not get serialized a second time.  You can do this using the `Content()` method instead.  Try it like this:

```
public ActionResult GetDataTable()
{
    // Build data table
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("DAYDATE", typeof(DateTime));
    dt.Columns.Add("SERIES1", typeof(double));
    dt.Rows.Add(new DateTime(2012, 5, 22, 0, 15, 0), 3.65);

    // Serialize data table using Json.Net to avoid circular reference error
    string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt,
        new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore,
            Formatting = Formatting.Indented
        });

    // Output is already serialized; return it as is (with the appropriate media type)
    return Content(output, "application/json");
}
```

In my testing, the above will produce the following output, which I think is what you are looking for:

```
[ { "DAYDATE": "2012-05-22T00:15:00", "SERIES1": 3.65 } ]
```

Comment: I tried directly returning dataTable  but I get circular reference error.  A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'System.Reflection.RuntimeModule'"

Comment: Does your controller inherit from `Controller` or `ApiController`?

Comment: it is inherited from 'Controller'

Comment: Thanks Brian. It worked. I do had to change the date format to javascript format using new JavaScriptDateTimeConverter(). Thanks again for your help