# How to have JSON String without characters like '\u0022' or '\' while converting DataTable to JSON String using NewtonSoft in .Net Core 3.1

Tags: c#, json, json.net, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

I am writing a simple API in .net core 3.1. To convert my DataTable to JSON String I am using NewtonSoft Library with following code:

```
string JSONresult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt, Formatting.Indented);
return Json (new { JSONresult });
```

The output I am getting is JSON String but it has so many characters like '\u0022' **which I know its for double quotes.**

```
{"jsoNresult":"[\r\n  {\r\n    \u0022ID\u0022: 2,\r\n    \u0022FunctionalityName\u0022: \u0022User Upload\u0022,\r\n    \u0022FunctionalityDescription\u0022: \u0022For Bulk Uploading User At Once\u0022,\r\n    \u0022TableName\u0022: \u0022tablename\u0022,\r\n    \u0022ValidationSP\u0022: \u0022user_Validate\u0022,\r\n    \u0022InsertSP\u0022: \u0022Insert_User\u0022\r\n  }\r\n]"}
```

All I Want is:

```
{"jsoNresult":"[{"ID": "2","FunctionalityName": "User Upload","FunctionalityDescription": "For Bulk Uploading User At Once","TableName": "tablename","ValidationSP": "user_Validate","InsertSP": "Insert_User"}]"}
```

I am new in c#, but having previously worked on Flask or even spring boot, they returns clear json string.

So How do I achieve what I want in .net core 3.1. 
PS: I know the use of `Formatting.Indented` , I can have serialized string with or without it

Comment: You could do `.Replace` on JSONresult and replace all `"\u0022"` with `""`

Comment: Maybe the following link can help you: [convert datatable to json in c-sharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17398019/convert-datatable-to-json-in-c-sharp)? I think the problem is that you directly pass your datatable object to the serializer.

Comment: @LukaKostic it will work for "" but what if there are different characters?

Comment: If I may ask, what functional problem is this causing? Will something downstream fail? Or is it a case of human readability?

Comment: Read the docs about: [How to serialize and deserialize (marshal and unmarshal) JSON in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to), especially in relation to the non-ASCII char *treatment* and Encoding.

Comment: that look like you should trim all values before serialize or trim should be part of serialize (there is example https://stackoverflow.com/a/19272300/5888230)

Comment: It looks like you've got a JSON string which itself encodes a JSON string (`\u0022` is a quote character). Chances are that you should just `return Json(new { JSONresult = dt })`

Comment: is the double serialisation intended?

Comment: And the expected result is an invalid Json `"jsoNresult": "[{"` … `"}]"` ? Do you want `"jsoNresult": [{` … `}]}` where jsoNresult is a table of object? And `Formatting.Indented` is about intending it has no power over double quote. It only try to make a json pretty by adding tabs and new line

Comment: Looks like you are double-serializing your JSON along the lines of [JSON.NET Parser *seems* to be double serializing my objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25559179/3744182) -- maybe `System.Text.Json` doesn't support `DataTable`?  So, don't do that.  If you want to use Json.NET in ASP.NET Core 3.1 see [Where did IMvcBuilder AddJsonOptions go in .Net Core 3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25559179/3744182).  To return raw, serialized JSON without replacing the serializer see [Return “raw” json in ASP.NET Core 2.0 Web Api](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48336680/3744182).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invalid format with Json when converting DataTable with Json.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19156485/10263)

Comment: Alternatively, you could add a custom `JsonConverter<DataTable>` like the `DataTableConverter` in [Serialize DataSet with current version of System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59780446/3744182).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first clue is that your JSON string

```
{"jsoNresult":"[\r\n  {\r\n    \u0022ID\u0022: 2,\r\n    \u0022FunctionalityName\u0022: \u0022User Upload\u0022,\r\n    \u0022FunctionalityDescription\u0022: \u0022For Bulk Uploading User At Once\u0022,\r\n    \u0022TableName\u0022: \u0022tablename\u0022,\r\n    \u0022ValidationSP\u0022: \u0022user_Validate\u0022,\r\n    \u0022InsertSP\u0022: \u0022Insert_User\u0022\r\n  }\r\n]"}
```

Looks like it contains a JSON string: `[\r\n  {\r\n    \u0022ID\u0022` looks a lot like JSON, bearing in mind that `\u0022` is the quote `"` character (the ascii character with value 0x22 is `"`).

From this we can conclude that the code:

```
string JSONresult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt, Formatting.Indented);
return Json (new { JSONresult });
```

Is actually encoding the JSON twice. Once is obviously the `JsonConvert.SerializeObject`, but the other is probably the `Json` object.

From this it's fairly clear that `Json` expects an object to serialize, and it will do the serialization itself. You don't need to pass it a serialized string.

This is supported [by the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controller.json?view=aspnetcore-3.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_Controller_Json_System_Object_), which says:

> Creates a JsonResult object that serializes the specified data object to JSON.

So try:

```
return Json(new { JSONresult = dt })
```

Comment: your answer makes sense but the code is throwing "A possible object cycle was detected which is not supported. This can either be due to a cycle or if the object depth is larger than the maximum allowed depth of 32." this error

Comment: Interesting, sounds like `Json` found something that Json.net was fine with. I assume you're using asp.net core -- if you are, you can configure it to use Json.net: [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42290811/how-to-use-newtonsoft-json-as-default-in-asp-net-core-web-api)

Comment: @elpidaguy and everybody else stumbling over this error: Just add `new JsonSerializerSettings { PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects,         TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects, NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore }` to your `JsonConvert.SerializeObject()` method and the error is gone.

Answer (score -1):

Try encode the serialized object and check it

```
   string Encodedresult= HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(JSONresult))
```

Comment: This is not replacing the \u0022 characters.