# Why does System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializer encode double-quotes instead of merely escaping them?

Tags: .net, json, jsonserializer, system.text.json

I am wracking my brain about this and can't figure out why or how to fix it.

This test should pass:

```cs
[Test]
public void EncodingTest()
{
    var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize("\"");

    Assert.AreEqual("\\\"", json);
}
```

but it doesn't.  It's saying that a double-quote `"` in a string should be translated to `\"`, which is (fairly universally) the preferred serialization for this character.  (See *string* at [json.org](https://www.json.org/json-en.html).)

But what's actually happening is that it gets encoded as `\u0022` which is the unicode code-point for it.

I understand that `\u0022` is *allowed*, but it's horribly unreadable.

I've found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61871060/how-to-have-json-string-without-characters-like-u0022-or-while-converting) which pointed me to

- [GH issue dotnet/runtime #29879](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/29879)
- [GH issue dotnet/runtime #29374](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/29374)
- [GH PR dotnet/corefx 39524](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/39524) which includes a [test case](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/39524/files/17f0ef2170909cb0e6f61a2ac071567c6adf636b#diff-587c2c60c3e232695ccd4d66c31270ccR258) to explicitly ensure it encodes this way.

None of what I've read says how to get the `JsonSerializer` to just escape it (like *every other serializer I've seen*).

Comment: You could check to see whether `System.Text.Encodings.Web.JavaScriptEncoder.UnsafeRelaxedJsonEscaping` fixes things for you. See: [dotnet core System.Text.Json unescape unicode string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58003293/3744182).

Comment: Yes, that works.  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/688IOt.  Do note that the JSON generated is `"\""` (because JSON string literals are always surrounded by double quotes) so your assert needs to look like `Assert.AreEqual("\"\\\"\"", json);`

Comment: I thought I had tried that.  Works now anyway.  Thanks.